# OSError: No Default Input Device Available using CoLAB

Tags: python, nlp, speech-to-text, pyaudio

Unable to use the SpeechRecognition lib in CoLAB.

Code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Speak Anything: ")
    audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print("You said: {}".format(text))
    except:
        print('Wrong')
```

I pip installed the following:

```
!apt install libasound2-dev portaudio19-dev libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0 ffmpeg
!pip install pyaudio
!pip install ConfigParser
!apt-get install python-gnuradio-audio-portaudio
!python -m pip install pyaudio
!pip install SpeechRecognition
```

ERROR Showing:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-65e65421018d> in <module>()
      4 r = sr.Recognizer()
      5 
----> 6 with sr.Microphone() as source:
      7     print("Speak Anything: ")
      8     audio = r.listen(source)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyaudio.py in get_default_input_device_info(self)
    947         """
    948 
--> 949         device_index = pa.get_default_input_device()
    950         return self.get_device_info_by_index(device_index)
    951 

OSError: No Default Input Device Available
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

FYI, I am using Google CoLAB for this.
--Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“OSError: No Default Input Device Available” on Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59013743/2745495)

Answer (score 0):

This code works :

Source of the Javascript : https://gist.github.com/korakot/c21c3476c024ad6d56d5f48b0bca92be#file-record-py

```
# all imports
from IPython.display import Javascript
from google.colab import output
from base64 import b64decode
from io import BytesIO
!pip -q install pydub
from pydub import AudioSegment
!pip install -q ffmpeg-python
import ffmpeg

RECORD = """
const sleep = time => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time))
const b2text = blob => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onloadend = e => resolve(e.target.result)
  reader.onerror = e => reject(new Error("Failed to read blob"))
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
})
var recordUntilSilence = time => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  let stream, recorder, chunks, blob, text, audioContext, analyser, dataArr, silenceStart, threshold = 50, silenceDelay = 2000
  try {
    stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
  } catch (err) {
    return reject(new Error("Failed to get media stream"))
  }
  audioContext = new AudioContext()
  const source = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream)
  analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser()
  analyser.fftSize = 512
  dataArr = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount)
  source.connect(analyser)
  recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream)
  chunks = []
  recorder.ondataavailable = e => chunks.push(e.data)
  recorder.onstop = async () => {
    blob = new Blob(chunks)
    try {
      text = await b2text(blob)
      resolve(text)
    } catch (err) {
      reject(new Error("Failed to convert blob to text"))
    }
  }
  recorder.onerror = e => reject(new Error("Recorder error"))
  recorder.start()
  const checkSilence = () => {
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArr)
    const avg = dataArr.reduce((p, c) => p + c, 0) / dataArr.length

    if (avg < threshold) {
      if (silenceStart === null) silenceStart = new Date().getTime()
      else if (new Date().getTime() - silenceStart > silenceDelay) {
        recorder.stop()
        audioContext.close()
        return
      }
    } else {
      silenceStart = null
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(checkSilence)
  }
  silenceStart = null
  checkSilence()
})
console.log("JavaScript code executed successfully.")
"""

def fix_riff_header(binary):
  process = (ffmpeg
    .input('pipe:0')
    .output('pipe:1', format='wav')
    .run_async(pipe_stdin=True, pipe_stdout=True, pipe_stderr=True, quiet=True, overwrite_output=True)
  )
  output, err = process.communicate(input=binary)
  
  riff_chunk_size = len(output) - 8
  # Break up the chunk size into four bytes, held in b.
  q = riff_chunk_size
  b = []
  for i in range(4):
      q, r = divmod(q, 256)
      b.append(r)

  # Replace bytes 4:8 in proc.stdout with the actual size of the RIFF chunk.
  riff = output[:4] + bytes(b) + output[8:]
  return riff

Global_user_response = 1

def record_until_silence():
  display(Javascript(RECORD))
  print("Listening...")
  time.sleep(1)
  s = output.eval_js('recordUntilSilence()')
  print("Done Listening !")
  print("s=",s)
  b = b64decode(s.split(',')[1])
  b = fix_riff_header(b)
  print("b=",b)
  global Global_user_response
  filename="User_Response_"+str(Global_user_response)+".wav"
  Global_user_response = Global_user_response+1
  with open(filename,'wb') as f:
    f.write(b)
  r = sr.Recognizer()
  try:
    detection = sr.AudioFile(filename)

    with detection as source:
        audio = r.record(source)

    word = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-US')
    # print(f"Chunk {i+1} transcription: {word}")

    return word
  except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
    return None
    
record_until_silence()
```

The code uses javascript to enable the mic, then listens and stores as a temporary file from wav, then uses Google Transcribe to turn it into t. The fix riff header is to fix the wav file header issue. This code worked for me as of 10/23.