# No Default Output Device Available

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to convert a wave into an audio stream on google colab, but I'm running into the following issue:

```
import pyaudio
pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
pa.get_default_output_device_info()
# error
# OSError: No Default Output Device Available
```

I saw on [pip3 install pyaudio on Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59013743/pip3-install-pyaudio-on-google-colab) that they needed to use some javascript to enable to the microphone, but I'm able to use `IPython.display.Audio` to play `.wav` files so I'm not sure how to resolve this error

Comment: See [PyAudio IOError: No Default Input Device Available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672155/pyaudio-ioerror-no-default-input-device-available)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm having trouble getting the top response to be working in google colab

Comment: For reference, the main example here https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/#examples is throwing the same error. Not sure what colab is looking for in terms of a device outptu