# Microphone isn't detecting in colab voice to text python script.. gives error OSError: No Default Input Device Available

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory, pyaudio

I tried to code a microphone voice to text converting script using python in google colab.. But it isn't detecting the mic.. and gives this error..

```
No Default Input Device Available
```

This is my code

```
!apt-get install python3-pyaudio

# Install the required libraries
        
!pip install SpeechRecognition
```

```
# Import the necessary libraries
import speech_recognition as sr

# Function to convert microphone input to text
def microphone_to_text():
    recognizer = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        audio = recognizer.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
        print("You said: " + text)
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Sorry, I couldn't understand the audio.")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Could not request results; {0}".format(e))

# Convert microphone input to text
microphone_to_text()
```

I need to modify this so that the mic can be detected.
I used the javascript shown here ["OSError: No Default Input Device Available" on Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59013743/oserror-no-default-input-device-available-on-google-colab) too, but the error remains.

Comment: Your code in Colab runs on a remote server, not in your local computer, so the code is using the non-existant server microphone, not your local one.